# Set child <ul> min-width to same as parent <li> width

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

I have the following jQuery code  which gets and applies the width of the parent li and applies the width to the child ul which works fine:

```
$('nav.boxnavigation ul li').each(function () {
    $(this).find('ul').width($(this).outerWidth(true));
});
```

I want to use this but instead set this to min-width rather than width, i know this is potentially using .css but cannot get this to work, I am unsure exactly what the code above is doing above to set the width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the above code you need to use the below one:

```
$('nav.boxnavigation ul li').each(function () {
    $(this).find('ul').css("min-width", $(this).outerWidth(true));
});
```

So this would work.